# expectation by reasoning

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

An unbiased die is successively rolled. Let $X$ and $Y$ denote, respectively, the number of rolls necessary to obtain a six and a five. $E[X]=  6$.

find $E[X \mid Y=1]$

Iam stuck on this. Iam thinking that if it requires one throw to get a 'five' then if i start throwing then the first throw is a 'five',since it was not a 'six' i need to keep on throwing ,but then i already threw the dice once therefore:     $E[X \mid Y=1] =  E[X] -1 $

but wrong according to my book so can someone explain whats wrong with my reasoning

Comment: I changed \vert to \mid.  The latter gives proper spacing; the former does not.  Thus I changed $E[X\vert Y=1]$ to $E[X\mid Y=1]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yeah but why should i not count the first throw as starting my attempt to get a $6$, even tough i know that my first throw will result in a 5 @Michael Hardy

Comment: Your first throw _is_ included among those needed to get a $6$.  Since it is included, the average number of throws needed to get a $6$ in those cases in which the first throw resulted in a $5$, is $1$ more than the average number of throws needed to get a $6$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

If the first trial yielded a $5$, then you're starting with the second trial in your attempt to get a $6$.  So it's $1$ plus the average number of trials needed to get a $6$, i.e. it's $1+6$.